# Spring cache set expire time dinamically - Caffeine

Tags: spring-cache, caffeine

I use an authentication API to get a token and use other services. This API returns the token and expire time. It's possible to get the expire time it returns and set expire_after_write with these value? Currently this property is in application.properties, but I'm afraid that someday the service provider change expire_time and we get some errors because the token is expired

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set a [per-entry policy](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Eviction#time-based) to evaluate the entry and determine the expiration time. As the token won't be modified within the cache, you can use `expireAfterCreate` and have the other methods return the `currentDuration` to not modify it. From the docs,

```
LoadingCache<Key, Graph> graphs = Caffeine.newBuilder()
    .expireAfter(new Expiry<Key, Graph>() {
      public long expireAfterCreate(Key key, Graph graph, long currentTime) {
        // Use wall clock time, rather than nanotime, if from an external resource
        long seconds = graph.creationDate().plusHours(5)
            .minus(System.currentTimeMillis(), MILLIS)
            .toEpochSecond();
        return TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(seconds);
      }
      public long expireAfterUpdate(Key key, Graph graph, 
          long currentTime, long currentDuration) {
        return currentDuration;
      }
      public long expireAfterRead(Key key, Graph graph,
          long currentTime, long currentDuration) {
        return currentDuration;
      }
    })
    .build(key -> createExpensiveGraph(key));
```

Answer (score 0):

By setting custom Expiry instance, we can set the expiry time at each entry level.

Example

```
Cache<Integer, Employee> cache = Caffeine.newBuilder().expireAfter(new Expiry<Integer, Employee>() {
    @Override
    public long expireAfterCreate(Integer key, Employee emp, long currentTime) {
        return TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(emp.getExpiryTime());
    }

    @Override
    public long expireAfterUpdate(Integer key, Employee emp, long currentTime, long currentDuration) {
        return currentDuration;
    }

    @Override
    public long expireAfterRead(Integer key, Employee emp, long currentTime, long currentDuration) {
        return currentDuration;
    }
}).build();
```

Reference [link](https://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.com/2021/04/caffeine-set-custom-eviction-policy.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final Expiry<Object, Item<?>> POLICY = new Expiry<>() {
    @Override
    public long expireAfterCreate(Object key, Item<?> value, long currentTime) {
        return value.expiredAt - currentTime;
    }

    @Override
    public long expireAfterUpdate(Object key, Item<?> value, long currentTime, @NonNegative long currentDuration) {
        return currentDuration;
    }

    @Override
    public long expireAfterRead(Object key, Item<?> value, long currentTime, @NonNegative long currentDuration) {
        return currentDuration;
    }
};

Cache<Key, Item<Value>> cache = Caffeine.newBuilder().expireAfter(POLICY).build();

private static class Item<V> {
    private final V value;
    private final long expiredAt;

    Item(final V value, final long ttlMs) {
        this.value = value;
        this.expiredAt = Ticker.systemTicker().read() + TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(ttlMs);
    }
}
```